# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in FROM clause.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

It keeps telling me syntax error in FROM clause. Any thought on fixing this code? I followed the tutorial 100%, somehow this error keeps happen. Also I'm using VS2019 and Microsoft Access 365. This is visual basic .net form.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim cmdlog As OleDbCommand
    Dim drlog As OleDbDataReader
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Login.Click
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\Jane\Documents\MYSJ GA\MySJ GA\bin\Debug\Mysejahtera1.accdb")

        Dim cmdlog As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from user log in where [user_ID]='" & textBoxuser.Text & "' and [user_pw]='" & textBoxpw.Text & "'", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim drlog As OleDbDataReader = cmdlog.ExecuteReader
        If drlog.Read() = True Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form4.Show()
            MsgBox("login successfully")
        Else
            MsgBox("login failed")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If the name of your table has spaces in it put square brackets around it [user log in].  Your SQL is assuming there is a table called `user` and doesn't know what to do with `log` and `in`

Comment: Also, use parameters rather than string concatenation to build your WHERE clause. Apart from the SQL injection vulnerability  - which you may argue is not an issue in your situation - it's just easier to code and to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use square brackets in table name:
"Select * from **[user log in]** where [user_ID]='"